# Adding frappe gantt to AdminLTE Dashboard

Tags: html, web, frameworks, gantt-chart, adminlte

I have been editing the frappe gantt(https://frappe.io/gantt) and now I want to add it to the dashboard called admin lte (https://adminlte.io/)

but I couldnt add it.
I added the code for the gantt chart to the admin LTE dashboard but it would not appear the gantt chart? idk whats the problem?

Can someone help me figure whats the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can Work with https://github.com/mymi14s/frappevue_adminlte

> Vue-based AdminLTE dashboard for Frappe and ERPNext

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31891187)